# Creating temporary view in couchdb using node-couchdb-api

Tags: node.js, couchdb

I am trying to connect couchdb using node-couchdb-api at nodejs level as mentioned in the following link http://dominicbarnes.us/node-couchdb-api/.My couchdb version is 1.1.1 and nodejs version is 0.6.10.

For creating temporary view as mentioned in api http://dominicbarnes.us/node-couchdb-api/api/database/tempView.html I have written the following code.

```
var couchdb = require("couchdb-api");
var server = couchdb.srv(localhost, 5984, false, false);
var db = server.db("test");
var map = function (doc) {
emit(null, 1);
};
var reduce = "_sum";
var query = { include_docs: true };
db.tempView(map, reduce, query, function (err, response) {
console.log(response);
});
```

But i am facing the following problem.

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\couchdb-api>node server.js
node.js:201
throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\couchdb-api\lib\util.js:24:39
at Array.map (native)
at Object.formatFunction (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\couchdb-api\lib\util.js:22:25)
at Object.tempView (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\couchdb-api\lib\database.js:285:28)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\couchdb-api\server.js:27:4)
at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
at Array.0 (module.js:479:10)
```

please suggest me to resolve the issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey there, I'm the creator of this module and I've successfully reproduced your problem. I have found the bug and a new version will be posted asap. (within the next 20-30 min)

Comment: In the meantime, add some whitespace in front of `emit(null, 1);` and that will clear up your problem. (I added a little "pretty-printer" for function bodies that strips out the leading whitespace so it doesn't look wonky in Futon, that's where the bug came from)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sorry about the problem you were experiencing. I'm the creator of that module, and I've just pushed version 1.1.2 up to NPM which addresses your problem. (and includes a unit test to make sure it doesn't happen again)

Just update to the latest version via `npm update couchdb-api` and you should be set to go. Let me know if you have further issues.

Comment: In sincere appreciation of your valuable help, please accept my respect. Your latest package is working but when we update couchdb-api with npm, Still I am facing the problem. So, I have downloaded the latest couchdb-api package and replaced in the node_modules. Sorry for again bothering you, as for now I am able to get the temporary view from the db without admin is created in couchdb, but if admin is at couchdb level cannot get the tempview from the db. 
    { error: 'unauthorized', reason: 'You are not a db or server admin.' } So please suggest me how to get temp view with admin privileges.

Comment: Hmm, can't believe I never added documentation about auth. To add your username/password, you need to set `server.auth = "user:pass";` OR `server.auth = [ "user", "pass" ];`